# My question was closed as duplicate but I couldn't find out if the question it was a duplicate of that question

Tags: support, reopen-request

[My question](https://superuser.com/questions/964486/i-uninstall-dnsunlocker-but-its-adware-still-terrorizes-my-pc) about some adware on my PC which I couldn't remove was closed and marked as a duplicate of 
[this question](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc) yet I think it has nothing to do with my question.

I couldn't answer it because of the adware which had invaded the link to my question so I couldn't access my question in any way.

I comment underneath the possible duplicate message before the adware became more infectious saying "The adware has taken over the link" But then he replied "You should be on a different computer" the only problem is, **I do not have another computer.** After finally gaining access to my question 2 days later (adware still on PC and invading other links), the question was closed as Duplicate.

The question that was suggested to me **did not** have any information about adware, it was only about Spyware, Malware, Rootkits, Viruses, etc And nothing about adware.

Comment: The duplicate provides information on how to remove malware, which is what you are infected with, [DNSUnlocker](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/587771/infected-withdnsunlocker-browser-hijacker-adware/) is easily removed.  I only provided the link so you can solve the problem, but the information i the duplicate question WILL SOLVE THE PROBLEM for you.

Comment: Try the solutions in the "duplicate".  If none of them work, update your question with what you tried and the results.  That will provide a basis to get more specific answers.

Comment: The solutions in the duplicate never worked but I'm still trying to uninstall it

Comment: @Mrfunny744 - I know for a fact Malwarebytes will remove the malicious infection your asking about.  So you have tried all the solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That duplicate link **does** cover adware. It is just not mentioned in the **title** of the question.

- The accepted answer makes reference to this "Nastier, in that it won't just show **ads**, install a toolbar, or use your computer as a zombie anymore.".
- Another answer "General symptoms for malware can be anything. The usual are: ... **Adverts popping up at random** ..." In short **adware** is **malware**.

As an aside, I've edited the title of the duplicate link to include "adware" as well as all the other names for the various nasties.

Note that there is no formal definition for any of theses nasties and there is a lot of overlap in how people use the names. One nasty program can fall into several of these categories.

You will also hear about "trojans". They also fall into the category called "malware".